# Separator only between operations

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I have to make multiplication table, which for n = 3 look like this:

```
1 x 1 = 1 | 1 x 2 = 2 | 1 x 3 = 3 
2 x 1 = 2 | 2 x 2 = 4 | 2 x 3 = 6 
3 x 1 = 3 | 3 x 2 = 6 | 3 x 3 = 9
```

For now my code look like this:

```
var n = 3;
var result;

for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    var result = '';
    for(j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
        result += ` ${i} * ${j} = ${i * j}`;
    }
    console.log(result);
}
```

My result is:

```
1 x 1 = 1  1 x 2 = 2  1 x 3 = 3 
2 x 1 = 2  2 x 2 = 4  2 x 3 = 6 
3 x 1 = 3  3 x 2 = 6  3 x 3 = 9
```

And I have no idea how to add "|" separate only between math operation. If I add "|" at the end of result variable, I will get it also after last operation, but i don't want it.

Comment: The code you're showing doesn't print the result you're showing. You should have some code that prints out the expression, not just the result. You would then just print out a ` |` after each expression if it's not the last one in a line.

Comment: So don't add the separator for the last operation in the row...

Comment: @sosick added a simple solution for you, let me know if it helps. Best of luck!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can append the | to the end when it is not the last row.

```js
var n = 3;
var result;

for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    var result = '';
    for(j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
        result += ` ${i} * ${j} = ${i * j}`;
        if(j != n)
        {
          result += ' |';
        }
    }
    console.log(result);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can add check using modulo operator `%` or just `j != n` to see if its the last part in row and add `|` based on that condition.

```js
var n = 3;
var result;

for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
  var result = '';
  for (j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
    result += ` ${i} * ${j} = ${i * j}`;
    result += j % n ? ' |' : ''
  }
  console.log(result);
}
```

You could do this with `Array.from()` method and `join`.

```js
var n = 4;

const result = Array.from(Array(n), (e, i) => {
  i += 1
  return Array.from(Array(n), (a, j) => {
    j += 1
    return `${i} * ${j} = ${i * j}` + (j != n ? ' | ' : '')
  }).join('')
}).join('\n')

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could add a check with a [logical AND `&&`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_AND_()) and the string. It returns either the empty string, or the separator.

```js
var n = 3,
    result,
    i, j;

for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    result = '';
    for (j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
        result += result && ' |';
        result += ` ${i} * ${j} = ${i * j}`;
    }
    console.log(result);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than add the pipe to the end of each item, it is simpler to add it to the start of each item except for the first item:

```js
var n = 3;
var result;

for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    var result = '';
    for(j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
        if(j !== 1)
        {
          result += ' | ';
        }
        result += `${i} * ${j} = ${i * j}`;
        
    }
    console.log(result);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would probably do this with some `range` function (such that `range(3, 7) //=> [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]`, for instance) and then `map` over an outer and an inner range, something like this:

```js
const range = (b, e) => Array.from({length: e - b + 1}, (_, i) => b + i)

const multTable = (m, n) => range(1, n).map(i => range(1, m).map(
  j => `${i} x ${j} = ${i * j}`
).join(' | ')).join('\n')

console.log(multTable(3, 3))
```

This will stop lining up well as soon as your products or factors hit double-digits.  If that's a concern, you might replace `join(' | ')` with `join('\t|\t')`.  It won't be perfect, but it'll likely be better.

Comment: Although definitely more idiomatic, this would be horribly inefficient in the long run as a new array gets constructed from scratch in each inner loop. In a real world app you'd probably be better off implementing `range` as a generator, but in this case you'll also need you own `map`, `join` and friends...

Comment: @georg: I'm more concerned here with the API than with performance, but I'd be really surprised if this were "horribly inefficient" for anything like the scale we'd want for a multiplication table.  But if there were problems, we could easily create that inner range only once, with only slightly less clean code.

Comment: Why do you think a generator would be better for creating a short fixed-length collection of numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
var n = 3;
var result;

for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
   var result = '';
   for(j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
      if(j!=n)
         result += ` ${i} * ${j} = ${i * j}` + '|';
      else
         result += ` ${i} * ${j} = ${i * j}`;
   }

console.log(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
var n = 3;
var result = '';

for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    var result = '';
    for(j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
        result.length && result += '|';
        result += ` ${i} * ${j} = ${i * j}`;
    }
    console.log(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For all n :

```js
function table(n){
    var i, j;
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        var result = '';
        for(j = 1; j <= n - 1; j++)
            result += ` ${i} x ${j} = ${i * j} |`;
        result += ` ${i} x ${j} = ${i * j}`
        console.log(result);
    }
}
table(1);
table(2);
table(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use an array to collect the results, then [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) the parts with `|`

```js
var n = 3;
var result;

for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    result = [];
    for (let j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
        result.push(`${i} * ${j} = ${i * j}`);
    }
    console.log(result.join(' | '));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to remove the last occurence of "|" in the loop with [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice):

```js
var n = 3;
var result;

for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
  var result = '';
  for (var j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
    result += ` ${i} * ${j} = ${i * j} |`;
  }
  result = result.slice(0, -1);
  console.log(result)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
let n =3;
[...Array(n)].map((_,i,a)=>
  console.log(a.map((_,j)=>`${i+1} * ${++j} = ${(i+1)*j}`).join(' | ')));
```

```js
let n =3;
[...Array(n)].map((_,i,a)=>console.log(a.map((_,j)=>`${i+1} * ${++j} = ${(i+1)*j}`).join(' | ')));
```